# Can I move Steam notification popups?

Tags: steam

During a game that I love to play ([League of Legends](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/league-of-legends/info)), if you are running the game through the Steam interface, the notifications appear at the bottom right hand corner and cover a vital part of the interface (the map).

Is there a way to change where these notifications appear?

THis is the contents of my steamscheme.res file:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// old-style vgui description file
// currently used only for the BaseSettings, Colors LayoutTemplates and Fonts sections
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

actually, that's all I'll paste...maybe the file has changed according to that message?

Comment: Interestingly, not all games use the bottom right corner. For whatever reason, Torchlight uses the top left.

Comment: Related: https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/api/ISteamUtils#SetOverlayNotificationPosition (*void SetOverlayNotificationPosition*...)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can select the default position of the popup by editing the file `resource/styles/gameoverlay.styles` in the Steam directory and searching for the `Notifications.PanelPosition` variable. Possible values are `BottomRight`, `BottomLeft`, `TopRight` and `TopLeft`.

Note though that the default position can be overridden by the game. In which case, unless the developers have included an option to configure it, you're at a loss.

Comment: it's a non steam game, so i presume they couldn't override it...they hopefully wouldn't have gone that position by choice...thanks again, worked perfectly!

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, only game distributed by Steam can change the position of the overlay (in fact, only game using steamworks).

Comment: Ah ok, I assumed it was a native Steam game :)

Comment: You can no longer edit the file without it updating to replace it...

Comment: I don't have the rep to post a new answer here, but to prevent update replacement: copy steam.styles over to `\Steam\skins\<MyCustomNotification>\resource\styles' (you'll need to create the folder tree under skins, name the bit between <> however you like). Then, edit the Notifications as described in Sylvain's answer and restart steam. Pick the skin from Settings/Interface, restart again to apply is and your custom settings will not be wiped away.

Answer (score 4):

You can change it for your system but not currently for specific games.

You need to find the SteamScheme.res file in the resource folder (within your main Steam folder) and search for "Notifications.PanelPosition" (I think that's correct - if not, search for "Notification" and I'm sure you'll find it). It's defaulted to "BottomRight", you can change it to "TopRight" and so on. Don't think you can make it any more specific than that, though.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, but I was not able to find this entry...I'll edit my Q to contain my steamscheme.res file...the only search searching for "notif" was "NotificationBodyText"...would I have to add this line in somewhere?