# How to move a Steam pop-up notification to another edge of the screen?

Tags: steam

I want to move the Steam pop-up notification (when someone connected or someone start a game or when someone chats with me). So I want to move it to any another edge of the screen.

I found this tip: http://jasonwilliams400com.startlogic.com/snor/weeds/Swamp_Buzzards_Clan/Steam_Client/Steam_Notifications_Panel_Modifications.txt but this does not work with the new steam interface.

Also, I tried some AutoHotKey scripts to move the pop-up notification but nothing works.

EDIT : I tried to do like this : [Can I move Steam notification popups?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20085/can-i-move-steam-notification-popups) but this not works because the new steam version check this file on startup and change "BottomLeft" to "BottomRight". and the others answers not works too.

Comment: If Steam changes the file on startup, try setting it to 'Read-only'. The fact that the file still has the option suggests the solution should in theory still work.

Comment: Thanks but this not works, i tried but steam rename the file with .old at the end and create a new one.